# Expo React Native App unable to connect to IOT hotspot through Wi-Fi

Tags: react-native, expo, iot

I recently upgraded my applicaiton to be compliant to be Play Store's Android 13 compatiable. This used to work but now when I try to connect to IOT's hotspot it is unable to. I connect by changing the phone's WI-FI to the IOT's hotspot then I make a request to the IP using axios.

It works runned locally on android and IOS in Test Flight. It does not work if the device downloads it from the play store.

I'll list my packages below.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.10.7",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.17",
    "@use-expo/font": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "1.5.0",
    "expo": "49.0.11",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.10.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.5.10",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.12",
    "galio-framework": "^0.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-cool-speedometer": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-floating-label-input": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

I tried to log any errors, but nothing is returned for that value. The request immediately fails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.